# Java how to read from file, verify data and print

Tags: java, validation, input, output, readfile

I have a log of events in a text file it has one event per line, containing and separated by    spaces:

```
(a) the card number (16 digits, no spaces);
(b) the mode (B / T / F);
(c) item ON or OFF;
(d) the zone number; and
(e) the time in milliseconds since the epoch.

Example:
1234123412340001 B ON 3 1377222203257
1234123412340007 T ON 1 1377222238204
1234123412340003 F OFF 5 1377222275153
```

I need to create a program that reads all of the events in standard input and prints them out again to standard output

example output:

```
$ java TestEvent < event-log.txt
1234123412340001 B ON 3 1377222203257
1234123412340007 T ON 1 1377222238204
1234123412340003 F OFF 5 1377222275153
$
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public Event(String cardNumber, int mode, boolean on, int zone, long time) {

private String cardNumber;
private int mode;
private boolean on;
private int zone;
private long time;

}


     Scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

   public void TestEvent()
{
    Scanner sc = IOHelper.createScanner(("args[0])");
    while (in.hasNextLine()) // NOT at the end of the stream, more input is available
    {
        String thisLine = sc.nextLine(); // Get an entire line
        for (int index=0; index < thisLine.length(); index++)
        {
            char ch = thisLine.charAt(index);
            System.out.print(ch);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

My java knowledge is quite poor but basically I am asking how do I extract the data from the file and check that all of the data is there (Verify it is there) and print it out again?

*Full disclosure: this is not for any homework task. Simply for my own knowledge.

Comment: Your program won't compile. Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You can google a lot of examples for reading files. What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileInputStreamReader, make its obeject & then simply read line form file using readLine method.

when you get data from file then compare it with your requirement.

this whole thing put in to while loop & thats it.